# How to fetch each value separately using XPATH

Tags: xpath

**Trying to fetch each record** where the first token element contains the attribute names and the actual values are present from row number 2.

```
<tokens>
    <token>"HostRecordName","Change","IPAddress"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-plcws-001.paypalcorp.com","Deleted","10.185.254.56"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-plcws-002.paypalcorp.com","Deleted","10.185.254.57"</token>
    <token>"phx11-plcws-001.paypalcorp.com","Deleted","10.222.254.20"</token>
    <token>"phx11-plcws-002.paypalcorp.com","Deleted","10.222.254.21"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-apiws-001.paypalcorp.com","Added","10.185.254.56"</token>
    <token>"lvs1-apiws-002.paypalcorp.com","Added","10.185.254.57"</token>
    <token>"phx11-apiws-001.paypalcorp.com","Added","10.222.254.20"</token>
    <token>"phx11-apiws-002.paypalcorp.com","Added","10.222.254.21"</token>
</tokens>
```

Comment: it may help if you post the expected result and any other info that is relevant to your question.

Comment: CSV in XML? Beautiful.

Comment: It looks like you have asked this question before, with a different account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566923/how-to-fetch-each-value-separately-using-xpath

Answer (score 1):

To select just the first token element, you can use the following XPath to select the first token element, which uses the shorthand syntax indicating `position()` equals 1:

```
/tokens/token[1]
```

To select all of the "rows" from the second `token` element to the `last()`, you can use a predicate to test where `position()` is greater than 1:

```
/tokens/token[position() > 1]
```

If you wanted to select a particular "column" from any of the rows, you could `tokenize()` on `,`.

An example selecting the first "column" from the first "row" of data:

```
tokenize(/tokens/token[position() > 1][1], ",")[1]
```

If you need to extract the value between the quotes, you can use [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring), selecting from `2` to `string-length() - 2`